# How to fix my broken Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

Short story: Purpose: to make space in my SSD file where both Win10 and Ubuntu are installed, with 3 accounts each. At the moment I had attempted to move /home out to another partition in a different drive (HD). But I underestimated the procedure and now I cannot go inside the accounts although they do show.

The following may not be allowed, but I need to bring this to the attention of as many experts as possible. So feel free to modify this as you see it fit, and/or give me the opportunity to adapt it enough just so this can stay: Since there is already a thread started with "all the details needed by anyone wanting to help" I thought it would be more practical to just put a link to it here. So, can I go ahead and put the link, or should I copy/paste all the info from the other site?

Comment: *"now I cannot go inside the accounts although they do show"* you mean the accounts on your ubuntu? did you try the GUI login only or did you try the console too?

Comment: Well, Ubuntu does load when I select it in my dual boot list with Grub2. No problem with that. But once I enter my password via the GUI then the screen flashes and just brings me back to where I was. It does not tell me that the password is wrong, it seems to accept it. But then it kicks me right out. 
I have not tried accessing the accounts via the Terminal. 2 be continued...

Comment: I think I was able to access the Guest account, but then I would not be able to access anything via the Terminal, even when using sudo. 
I guess might as well give you the URL to that other thread:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2347111&p=13592203#post13592203

Comment: did you copy `/home` to the new drive *as root*? can you boot from a life distro and check permissions of the content of `/home` at the new hd drive?

Comment: one more question: what do you have in your `/etc/fstab`? (check from the live distro too...)

Comment: I did copy the account folders to a folder called home in the new partition in the other drive, with sudo cp (maybe not the best). Then I added the mounting point in the etc/fstab file pointing to that home folder. But I don't think that is the same thing.
I will check the permissions, once I get back home (I'm at work now).
I would put here what I have in the fstab file, but I doubt it'll fit.

Comment: But you can see it here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2347111&p=13592403#post13592403
At the bottom

Comment: I think it's a permission problem either because all  folders inside `/home` are owned by root  (more likely)  or the new users have different UIDs (less likely)

Comment: This is great! So, the way you see it, as soon as I fix the permissions this will be back to normal? 
I would still need to do a proper moving of home though, right?

Comment: *" I fix the permissions this will be back to normal?"* cannot make promises, but the chance is there...

Comment: Btw, once I am ready to set up the permissions for each of the account folders, should they be 700? Or what exactly I should set'em up to?